# Official Stata command for bivariate normal probability density function

Tags: stata, normal-distribution

I see that Stata has `binormal` command for computing bivariate cumulative distribution function but not corresponding (official) command for computing bivariate probability density function. (Please let me know if I am wrong). I know that there is a user-written function `bnormpdf` for that but unlike the official commands like `normalden` for univariate probability density function, the variable to be generated appears at the right hand side.

```
bnormpdf x1 x2, rho(.2) dens(pdf_b) double
```

I was wondering whether this pattern will have any effects when programming, for example maximum likelihood (this may seem too broad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are worried about, but in Stata terms you have functions and commands the wrong way round here.

1. Commands and functions are totally disjoint in Stata.
2. A command may call a function and in Stata that is the only way to use a function. But a function may not call a command.
3. Users cannot write functions in Stata. (Users can write `egen` functions and Mata functions but neither of those categories is relevant here.) Only Stata's developers can write Stata functions.

Note that some (occasional) users of Stata prefer to ignore Stata's own terminology in discussing Stata, perhaps because they regard it as perverse. I don't recommend that. Stata's terminology choices are open to discussion, but you need to understand Stata's terminology before you can discuss it.

All that said, I don't think there is much to add on your question.

http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dfunctions.pdf documents `binormal()` which is, in Stata terms, a function, not a command.

`bnormpdf` (SSC) is in contrast not a function but a command.

However, nothing stops you using either or both within your own programs. The syntax is necessarily different, so you must use `bnormpdf` to create a new variable before you use that variable for your own purposes. You can't use a call to `bnormpdf` within some other command.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. But, I think that is not just restricted to the occasional user (which I am not) as you can see [here](http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/stats_packages/stata/stata_gen.htm) where `gen` is referred both as a function and a command (which according to the Stata manual is a command). Anyway, I will take that into account.

Comment: Users of all kinds can make mistakes, if you prefer to put it differently. But that page is referring to `gen` functions, which in context are functions such as `max()` and `sum()` that you can use with `generate`. That's not quite correct as you can use those functions with other commands, but the page points that out too. The page is _not_ confusing commands and functions, however.

Comment: I might have misunderstood that. Thanks once again.